# Design of three phase thyristor circuit for temperature controller

Tags: temperature, three-phase, thyristor

Circuit is powered by 3 phase, 415 V AC. This   is connected to nri halogen tubes to heat  a chamber up to 20 kW and 700℃. I have to control temp    using delta controller DTA 7272 which will sense temperature of the   chamber using a thermocouple and will give DC sense to the circuit. I want to know how the nri tubes will be programmed and will they glow dim or bright? (Nri tube is connected by output of the circuit.) So if PWM can cause heating?

- How can I programme frequency in output?
- Will it be effective?
- How do I sort out my duty cycle?

Three phase input and output is working using thyristors.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Quality of responses will be proportional to quality of question. Yours has sloppy punctuation and capitalisation. You are also asking us to search for the 'DTA7272' instead of telling us what it is and providing a link or summary. Please fix.

Comment: Dta 7272 us name of that temprature controller...

Comment: Sir i want you help in controlling heat of nri halogen tubes which are connected via outout of circuit (3 phase output).

Comment: The name of _what_ temperature controller? Please fix your original post.

Comment: Dear sir,i am new here and in electrical world too..i have knowledge of electronic and programming ..i want to know how to approach for controlling the nri heating tubes..

Comment: Go to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33192/nri-halogen.

Comment: oops,I am not having 20 points as i joined today..and with zero points i can just read ur msg,can not participate there..

Answer (score 1):

You have not told us what an 'nri halogen' is. We don't know if there is a neutral connection.

If your question is how to control a three-phase heater with thyristors and a temperature controller then this may be what you want.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBtJp3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- SSR is a three-phase solid state relay (SSR) which uses triacs to switch a three-phase load.
- The triacs are triggered by 'opto-coupling' the light from an LED in the SSR. When the internal LED turns on the triacs turn on.
- The easiest configuration is when the temperature controller has an SSR output. This gives an isolated signal to the LED and saves having to add another low-voltage power supply for the LED. I've shown it as a voltage source with a switch but it is usually a voltage source turned on and off by the controller. The output will be usually 6 to 12 V at up to 50 mA - enough to drive most SSRs.
- Selecting a 'zero-cross' SCR will minimise electrical interference as current will be switched on when voltage is near zero.